# Latex failed whilst using Manim

Tags: python, latex, manim

I am new to Manim and tried to create a matrix. I installed MacTex using the command
`brew install --cask mactex-no-gui`
and it all installed fine
I went to run my code in a jupyter file

```
%%manim -qm FirstExample
mat = np.array([[1, 0, 1], [2, 1, 0]])
class FirstExample(Scene):
    def construct(self):
        matr = Matrix(mat)
        self.play(matr)
```

and got the following error message
`RuntimeError: latex failed but did not produce a log file. Check your LaTeX installation.`

Not really sure what I have done wrong given I just followed the Manim installation guide so any help would be appreciated

Comment: Did you follow this [guide](https://docs.manim.community/en/stable/installation/jupyter.html) for jupyter notbooks?